# WXpython Tutorial

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to create a GUI project using WxPython. I want to know where I can get the full tutorial for Wx Python. 
I checked the tutorial on [Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/) but I'm sure it doesn't covering everything.

Where I can view something similar to MSDN library?

Answer (score 3):

There is no full tutorial for every single widget in wxPython. The zetcode tutorial shows a lot of the basics though. And if you download the wxPython demo, you'll have 99% of the widgets in a demo form. You can also check out my listing of good wxPython documentation sources:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/05/wxpython-documentation/

I wrote that before the Phoenix docs came out, so you might want to check those out too if you're using Phoenix or 2.9: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/index.html

I cover a bunch of various odds and ends in wxPython on my [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org) too.

Comment: Realistically, when I need to solve one of my own problems or if I'm looking for documentation to back up an SO answer I'm writing I find myself consulting Mike's blog **A LOT**. I wanted to add though that when I'm looking for sample code I find [AnotherTutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial) to be very helpful since it covers a wide range of widgets (although it is a bit daunting to read in its entirety. I do a search for the widget I need). It says it's for Linux but 99% of the code is OS independent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "AnotherTutorial" is a version of the zetcode tutorial. I think the author of zetcode put it on the wiki first, then spruced it up a bit for her own website. But as I mentioned, the wxPython demo is probably the closest that you'll get to a tutorial on every widget.